# MySQL query to get a list of posts that a user is not following

Tags: mysql

```
 id   username
| 1 | john
| 2 | mike
| 3 | Tim
| 4 | Jake
| 5 | Sam

follower_id    followed_id
|      1     |       3
|      1     |       4

post_id     author_id
|    1    |     5
|    2    |     4
|    3    |     5
```

John is following Tim and Jake. How would I return a list of posts that John is ***not*** following?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the table names as `user` , `user_to_follower` and `post`.

- Start with `post` table and do an **INNER JOIN** with the user table.
- Now, do a **LEFT JOIN** to the `user_to_follower` table. Since you want to consider all the users which are not being followed by 'John' and **have authored a post**
- Note that in the LEFT JOIN, variable 'JOHN' is set by `f.follower_id = 1` in the `ON` clause.
- Now, just filter out those users where **follower_id** `is null`.
- **This Join based solution is more efficient than using a Subquery.**

Try the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, p.id AS post_id 
FROM post AS p 
INNER JOIN user AS u ON p.author_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN user_to_follower AS f ON f.followed_id = u.id 
                                   AND f.follower_id = 1 
WHERE f.follower_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Again, thank you. Do you stay away from sub queries?

Comment: @onosendi I prefer finding solutions without a subquery. Even if I have to use a subquery, I try to look for [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) based solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  author_id NOT IN (SELECT f.followed_id
                         FROM   followers f
                         JOIN   users u ON f.follower_id = u.id
                         WHERE  username = 'John')
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is using `not exists` :

```
select * from posts 
where not exists (
    select 1 from followers 
    where 
    followers.follower_id = 1 
    and 
    followers.followed_id = posts.author_id
)
```